# Regex to check start & end and numbers only

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I want to validate if every number has a `,` on start and end and the complete string be like

```
,453,399,2093,11,309,      //true
,453,                      //true
323,453,                   //false
,343,323                   //false
```

I tried following but somehow it fails

```
/^(([0-9](,)?)*)+$/
/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a pattern at the start which matches `,num` and make this pattern to repeat one or more times. Then finally add a `,` and finish the regex by adding end of the line anchor `$`.

```
^(?:,\d+)+,$
```

or

```
^,(?:\d+,)+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yR0lI4/3)

Comment: yes, I was just understanding your answer and got it. Thanks alot

Comment: @epascarello Thanks alot man. Your site gave me alot of help in understanding regex. For the first time I made my own regex. Thanks again

Comment: Avinash please would you kindly confirm me if I have made a correct regex for following **32,43,23|30,302,32|95,49,95** with ^(((\d+,)*\d+)\|((\d+,)*\d+))*$

Comment: try `^\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\|\d+(?:,\d+)*)*$`